# First look at comments in code: How to add the Sum of amount of all opportunities and update that on Annual revenue field of account

Tags: trigger

```
set<string> setIds = new set<string>();
for(Account acc : Trigger.New)
{
    setIds.add(acc.id); 
}
List<Opportunity> opps = [Select Id, amount from Opportunity where id in : setIds]; 
Map<Id, List<Opportunity> > accountIdOppsMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
for( Opportunity opp : opps) 
{
    if(accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid) == null) 
    {
        accountIdOppsMap.put(opp.accountid, new List<Opportunity>());
    }
    accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid).add(opp);
}
for(Account Acc : accountIdOppsMap)
{
    for(Opportunity myLoopOpp : accountIdOppsMap)
    {
        // How to add the Sum of amount of all opportunities and update that on Annual revenue //field of account

    }
}
```

Comment: It isnt necessary that last two loops are correct !

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking for would be like this:

```
for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    record.AnnualRevenue = 0; // reset all values to zero
}
for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT Sum(Amount) Sum, AccountId AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.new GROUP BY AccountId]) {
    Trigger.newMap.get((Id)result.get('AccountId')).AnnualRevenue = (Decimal)result.get('Sum');
}
```

The first loop simply resets all values to zero for accounts with no opportunities, and the second loop uses an efficient query to sum all amounts at once, placing the total in appropriate record.

Comment: What about the map that I have used above the loops ???

Comment: @SohailBeyondVision If you needed additional processing, you might need to use a map. However, there's no need in this case because the map is already provided, and the aggregate query takes care of the math for you automatically. There's often many times when we can write far more efficient code than what appears in the typical tutorial.

Comment: Yes I got your point.... I think the code that you have wrote; this can be replaced with my entire code ? Am I right ??

Comment: Certainly! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Just wait let me check it

Comment: Its not updating the AnnualRevenue field